# How to run the execution module as a specific user?

Tags: salt-stack

I would like to manage users settings interfaced by `GSettings` in salt. I have a Python code that can manage the `GSettings`, but it needs to do that as a specific user.

Salt execution modules (and everything actually) by default run as a user that executed `salt-minion`, which is `root` by default. I couldn't find in the documentation information how to run a specific module as someone other.

I can walkaround it by executing a shell with `su -l <username>`, that in turn would call my Python code, but I hope there is an elegant build-in way, like an option `user: <username>` in the module.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to run a command as a specified user:

From a state, you can do something like this ([docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.run)):

```
mycommand:
  cmd.run:
    - name: python my_gsettings_script.py
    - runas: alternate_user
```

There is also an [execution module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cmdmod.html#salt.modules.cmdmod.run), that also provides a `runas` option.